# Accessing application settings from class library using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, application-settings

I'm trying to figure out how to access application settings in a class library. The application settings are read and build in a console application, and a project referenced class library must access these, as this library is the data access layer and need access to a connection string.

In the main console app I have this code - it works fine

```
   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, loadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

                Console.WriteLine($"Contents of Message Property: {config["Message"]}");
```

How do I access the information in a project referenced class library. I guess it shouldn't be necessary to re-read the json file with settings from each library?

Comment: It is not possible to retrieve the configuration from the console app and pass it as parameter to the class library?

Comment: Inject it when you create new instance of that class. Dependency Injection is used almost everywhere in .NET Core.